# Не могу поправить код bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

[image: bootstrap]

Скопировал с сайта исходники и добавил себе. Но отображается не правильно. Кто чем может помочь? Вот ссылка на сайт: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/media-slider-carousel-bs3

Comment: Добавьте код. По вашей картинке проблемы не найти.

Answer (score 0):

По вашей ссылке, там все правильно сделано. Испытывал с bootstrap 3.3.7, все работает нормально! На счет отображения, вы наверное что не подключили (jQuery например или bootstrap.js)